# Integrating Autocad Revit 12 to .net Application

Tags: integration, revit, revit-api

I have been tasked with integrating Revit 12 intoto my .NET application.  Can any one please help me and give me guidelines on how to begin this.  I am supposed to read the file and save it to my application like how I attach any other document.  I must also be able to view this file from my application.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to read from the file? You cannot read the data inside a revit file unless you are running a Revit API addin from within revit, outside of revit its not possible. You can get a thumbnail from the revit file, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start from the beginning..read this post so you can understand a little about Revit API: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/getting-started.html

Then you can go over the blog to gather more info to develop your application..

Also, there is the Autodesk Developer Center, where you'll find a lot of good info:
http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16777469